# how to calculate the velocity of an object using U and V flow vectors

Tags: image-processing, velocity, opticalflow

I am using the method of (Exploring New Representations and Applications for Motion Analysis) paper to find out the flow vectors of an object in matlab.

https://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/

is it possible to calculate the velocity of the object using U and V vectors?

Appreciate your help guys...

Regards

Comment: you know google right? https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow.step.html

Comment: sure and I checked that before and saw the equations of estimated velocity with u and v. but to be honest I couldn't do it in matlab as I am so new ..

Comment: I meant should I go through the steps that shown in mathwork page with [u v]^T,

Comment: Dear Piglet, this function will compute the optical flow of the images and then result the matrix of velocity magnitude. VSQ = step(opticalFlow,I) but in my case I already computes the flow vectors in the images .. and just want any relationship with the velocity to use